# Why is the nuclear binding energy per nucleon not constant at beginning?

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy, elements

I can understand, how it is constant after awhile, that due to the range of strong nuclear force the force is increasing linearly with the linear increase of the nucleon number, making it a constant.

But At the beginning, shouldn't the same would have been take place, the energy required to bind the nucleons per nucleon be constant as it is still inside the range of nuclear force, only in the heavy elements the range is exceeded and the nucleons does not possess enough binding energy as before contributing to the decrease in binding energy per nucleon.

Why is it in the start increasing?

[image]

Comment: The binding energy [is complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding energy of nuclei is the result of two players in the game - strong short-range nuclear force between all nucleons and long range electrostatic repulsion force between protons. Up to atomic mass 30 nuclei is "hungry for binding", meaning that overall nuclear force dominates over electrostatic repulsion, so adding more nucleons makes nuclei even more tightly coupled. (That's why building $\mathcal H$ thermonuclear reactor is a thing, because at low atomic mass numbers nuclei releases energy upon taking more "companions").

In the range of atomic mass $30-90$ is a *relative* stability island, where nobody dominates from this force pair. Adding or subtracting nucleons at this point doesn't changes binding energy much, because electrostatic repulsion is "on par" with strong nuclear force, so "things" are saturated.

Things change up the ladder from the atomic mass 90. Electrostatic repulsion between protons becomes a bit more dominating than strong nuclear force, so nuclei is becoming "hungry for divorce". Shooting some neutrons into such nuclei, especially with high atomic numbers like $\mathbb U^{238}$, makes high risk for such nuclei to split apart into more stable components. That's the principle of radioactivity (induced or sustainable, doesn't matter). Atoms in this range releases binding energy upon splitting apart, that's why having a nuclear reactor of $\text U^{238}$ is a thing.